# Mayaで作ったモデルをUnityに読み込んだのですが、sorting layerが効きません。

Tags: unity3d

Mayaで作ったモデルをUnityに読み込んだのですが、sorting layerが効きません。
スプライト以外は、sorting layerを設定できないのでしょうか。

よろしくおねがいいたします。

Answer (score 1):

スクリプトを作成することで設定することができます。
　
　スプライトを描画するSpriteRendererコンポーネントには、Inspector上にSortingLayerの設定項目がありますが、MeshRendererやSkinnedMeshRendererコンポーネントには、Inspector上にSortingLayerの設定項目がありません。
　一見設定できないように見えますが、SortingLayerのプロパティはMeshRendererやSkinnedMeshRendererの基底クラスであるRendererクラスが持っていますので、スクリプト上では設定できます。

```
class SampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private string m_layerName = "";

    void Start()
    {
        var render = GetComponent< MeshRenderer >();
        if( render != null )
        {
            render.sortingLayerName = m_layerName;
        }
    }
}
```

以下の記事に詳しい説明がありますので、ご参考ください。
http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/01/05/233000

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確認してみます。